# Odoo 11: Pass array to qweb template

Tags: odoo-11, qweb

I'm trying to pass an array from my controller to a QWeb template but can't achive to iterate through it...

--- Controller ---

```
return_projects = {}

for active_project in active_projects:
    hours = 0
    for analytic_line in active_project.line_ids:
        hours += analytic_line.unit_amount

    return_projects[active_project.id] = {
        "name": active_project.display_name,
        "hours": hours
    }

return http.request.render('mymodule_briefing.crm_page', {
    'projects': return_projects,
})
```

--- Template ---

```
<t t-foreach="projects" t-as="project">
<-- show project.name -->
<-- show project.hours-->
</t>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the loop, `project` is the project `id` so you need to use it to get project data (name and hours) from `projects`

***Example:***

```
<t t-foreach="projects" t-as="project_id">
    <div>
        <t t-esc="projects[project_id]['name']"/>
        <t t-esc="projects[project_id]['hours']"/>
    </div>
</t>
```

You can render the template using the project records:

```
return odoo.http.request.render('mymodule_briefing.crm_page', {
    'projects': active_projects,
})
```

And use the following code to loop over records and compute hours:

```
<t t-foreach="projects" t-as="project">
    <div>
        <t t-esc="project.name"/>
        <t t-esc="sum(line.unit_amount for line in project.line_ids)"/>
    </div>
</t>
```

Comment: Thank you @Kenly, it's working as expected!

As I have to do some operations before returning the object, I can't just pass the project records.